# Android MAP api key doesnt works in another project

Tags: android, google-maps

I created one project having mapactivity and mapview and it worked fine.but when i created another project on same pc it is showing couldnt connect factory client.any pointers how to sort it out.

Comment: did you added this one "<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />" in manifest file ??

Comment: i have added this as well as all required permissions.it shows only grid.i tried to regenerate md5 fingerprint,but its the same that i generated last time.

Comment: Have you tested this on Device or Emulator?

Comment: yes i have tested on device..the first proj working fine but the another project with same api key is not working.showing just a grid.

Answer (score 4):

I Predict this is the problem with your API key.When ever you integrate the goolge maps with your application you should generate a key and should be added in your app.I think this is the problem with your map showing the grid only.I had came over the same issue once.I predict this may be your problem.This [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/112044/GPSLocator-App-to-Find-Current-Nearest-Location-us) may help you to solve your problem.

Comment: One more link to help. http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android

Comment: Happy to help :-)...If it really helped to solve your problem,accept the ans and happy coding....

Comment: @sreedav I have already gone through those links and they are not much of help as md5 fingerprint that i am generating is same.so api key is same and its working in first project fine.so still iam stuck..:(

Comment: Can you share some code here?You are testing it in emulator or device?

Comment: trying on device..code iam not able to share as SO pointing ...Your post does not have much context to explain the code sections; please explain your scenario more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using different keystores for both the projects you are mentioning.

Comment: how can this be possible.ok i am nt sure about that but i did this. first generated a md5 fingerprint using java keytool by copying C:\Users\.android\debug.keystore into bin of jdk which i used to generate key and used.but the same key if i use in other project its not working..